# Render iFrame video using YouTubes JS API with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, iframe, youtube

I've tried looking around for examples but all i have is `youtube-react` `npm` packages which I don't want since I want to do it and learn it myself.

My issue is on the docs here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
It tells me to provide an anchor tag for Google to append the iFrame depending on what you pass it.

However, I have react on the server-side and use web-pack to compile it to the client-side my react component so far looks like :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import classnames from 'classnames'

const videoId = 'XxVg_s8xAms';

export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      YTid: videoId,
    }
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="youtubeComponent-wrapper">
        <div id="youtubePlayerAnchor"></div>
      </section>
    )
  }
})
```

I've tried adding the code from the developer docs into a `script` tag onto the client but nothing happens nothing in console nothing.

Is there any resources or could anyone point me in the right direction on how i'd go about handling this.

Thanks!

Comment: how are you loading the youtube iframe api?

Comment: @Davidlrnt I've been unable to load the youtube iframe api. Since the docs says I need to write a script tag to the DOM and send the API response to it but React complains when I try it.

Comment: you can add the script tag on the index.html where your react app renders without react involved, it loads the library globally so react will be able to access the methods later on. The only issues is that it loads the library asynchronously, so depending on how the app is set up the iframe api might not yet be loaded by the time react tries to access it, the other option is to load the library with the npm package youtube-player, https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-player

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could probably create a React component like this:

```
import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

let loadYT

export default class YouTube extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    if (!loadYT) {
      loadYT = new Promise((resolve) => {
        const tag = document.createElement('script')
        tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'
        const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag)
        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => resolve(window.YT)
      })
    }
    loadYT.then((YT) => {
      this.player = new YT.Player(this.youtubePlayerAnchor, {
        height: this.props.height || 390,
        width: this.props.width || 640,
        videoId: this.props.YTid,
        events: {
          onStateChange: this.onPlayerStateChange
        }
      })
    })
  }

  onPlayerStateChange = (e) => {
    if (typeof this.props.onStateChange === 'function') {
      this.props.onStateChange(e)
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <section className='youtubeComponent-wrapper'>
        <div ref={(r) => { this.youtubePlayerAnchor = r }}></div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

YouTube.propTypes = {
  YTid: PropTypes.string.required,
  width: PropTypes.number,
  height: PropTypes.number,
  onStateChange: PropTypes.func
}
```

Comment: Cheers! Used this as a base for a Vue component ;)